# Combine select helpers and predicate function to mutate in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to programmatically select which columns to mutate, based on a predicate function (e.g. `is.character`), *and* a "select helper" (e.g. `starts_with("Z")`) at the same time.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(V1 = "a", V2 = 1, Z1 = "a", Z2 = 1)
```

Desired output (`mutate_at(df, "Z1", paste, "b")` but without selecting `Z1` explicitely):

```
structure(list(V1 = "a", V2 = 1, Z1 = "a b", Z2 = 1), class = c(
  "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

In other words, how to "combine" `mutate_at(df, vars(starts_with("Z")), paste, "b")` and `mutate_if(df, is.character, paste, "b")` in a single mutate?

Comment: Predicate functions in `*_if` verbs aren't aware of column names, and select helpers in `*_at` verbs are **only** aware of column names, so neither will work "out of the box." I think you'll have to compute the names of the columns that you want to select using a custom function, and then use `mutate_at()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In newer versions of tidyselect and dplyr, we can use `where` to turn a predicate function into a select helper.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character) & starts_with("Z"), paste, "b"))

#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>   V1       V2 Z1       Z2
#>   <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 a         1 a b       1
```

We also have to use the newer `across` interface, since `mutate_at` is not compatible with `where`.

Answer (score 7):

Why not using two steps?

```
df %>%
  select_if(is.character) %>%
  select(starts_with("Z"))
```

Edit:

```
select_if(df, is.character) %>%
  select(starts_with("Z")) %>%
  names() %>%
  mutate_at(df, ., paste, "b")
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but I'd like to keep the others "un-mutated" columns too

Comment: @Aurèle you could add `%>% {mutate_at(df, names(.), paste, "b")}` to the end of this pipeline to get that. You have to specify `df` in 2 places, but I really don't think there's a way around that in this scenario.

Answer (score 4):

We can generate the `.predicate` for `mutate_if` with base functions:

```
df %>% mutate_if(sapply(., is.character) & startsWith(names(.), 'Z'), ~ paste(., 'b'))

# # A tibble: 1 x 4
#   V1       V2 Z1       Z2
#   <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 a         1 a b       1
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not three steps then ;)?

```
df2 <- df %>%
  select_if(is.character) %>%
  select(starts_with("Z")) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(paste(., "b")))

for (i in names(df2)) {
  df[[i]] <- df2[[i]]
}
```

Comment: I have looked for a dplyr function which can do the work of your `for` loop i.e. : replace a set of columns in a data frame (and add new ones if there are some new names in `df2`) with no success. Maybe it is needed and could be mamed `update`...

Comment: @pietrodito you can just use subassignment: `df[names(df2)] <- df2` will do the trick, and could be used to replace the loop here.